# How risky is it to disclose your IMEI number?

Tags: web-application, mobile, phone

What will happen if I have mistakenly given my Android phone IMEI number to my IT colleague at my work place? How risky is it? I have asked him to delete my IMEI number. How can I be sure that he is not using my IMEI number?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of any malicious misuse of another users IMEI number through my three years experience as a digital forensic investigator.
A quick google search shows that there are software to change the IMEI number, if it works or not i haven't tested. There might be a risk that a user could impose another by using his/hers IMEI number.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Information Security. The answers in the linked duplicate posts are much more complete and list some (rare.minor) risks of disclosing the IMEI number.